# Equivalent of strftime in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

After migrating my SQLite database to Postgres on the development server, I get the

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, date) does not exist
```

Is there a function I could use to keep the functionality across my app?

Edit: tried using to_char but failed miserably. In particular, I do not understand how to implement it in a construction such as

```
def self.query_by_year_month(y, m)
  where("strftime('%Y', date) = ? and strftime('%m', date) = ?", y, m)
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it is a great time to start learning SQL! Made my method work using the following code:

```
  def self.query_by_year_month(y, m)
    where("extract(year from date) = ? and extract(month from date) = ?", y, m)
  end
```

Comment: On the one hand, you'll probably get a sequential scan from that WHERE clause.  On the other hand, you get to learn more SQL!

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might be [to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

One alternative is to implement the behavior of strftime() as a user-defined function. (Named "strftime", of course.)

Comment: Could to_char be used in the view layer?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `date_part()`. See the documentation here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html