# sqlite vs postgreql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

Quick questions, haven't been able to find concrete answers about this questions.  I'm guessing it's because the answer is obvious.

I know that in order to push a rails app to Heroku a postgreql database is required.  I have only been working with the rails default database sqlite3.

How different is postgreql?  Will I be able to make the same activerecord calls and queries that I do with a sqlite3 database with a postgresql database?

Comment: 95% of your ActiveRecord code will be the same. Unless your application is very complicated, you're probably not using SQLite specific features.

Comment: @FarleyKnight: Not really, there are many subtle differences between databases that will trip you up: type handling, case sensitivity of LIKE and `=`, string length handling in `varchar(n)` columns, GROUP BY behavior, date and time functions, case sensitivity of identifiers, ... If the app is trivial then the differences probably won't hurt too much. Using SQLite as a default database was a stupid marketting-drvien decision from the Rails people.

Comment: Install PostgreSQL in your development environment, ditch SQLite for development, and I hope you have a thorough test suite.

Comment: If you don't use any fancy stuff you can go without ever having issues. At least from my experience with this app: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I don't believe any of my app's with the goal of pushing them to Heroku will be complicated at all.

Comment: There are some differences when it comes to field limits.  if you are using long strings it very large numbers (64 bit ints) make sure to setup your limits correctly

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is possible to keep a development database in SQLite, while deploying to Heroku and having PG in production. It is not recommended, but totally possible. Check out Michael Hartl's tutorial, he shows just that in action ([here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-heroku_setup)).

Switching to PG is pretty painless, though. Here's a good [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql). It also shows how to migrate the database. There are a couple of gotchas in the queries, which you might encounter: strftime, for example, does not work with PG queries. Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119978/equivalent-of-strftime-in-postgres/20122495#20122495).

You'll also have to start the PG server manually.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start
```

Other than that you will have little or no problems, Postrgres is an amazing tool, but a couple of Postgres and SQL tutorials won't hurt.