# heroku ERROR: function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have following sql in my controller.

```
@microposts = Micropost.where("strftime('%Y%m', microposts.created_at) = '"+params[:yyyymm]+"'").order(:id).page[:page]
```

and

```
@archives = Micropost.group("strftime('%Y%m', microposts.created_at)").order("strftime('%Y%m', microposts.created_at) desc").count
```

This works fine in my development environment. But after deploying in heroku it gives me the below error while saving the record.

> heroku ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist

How should I rewrite?

Comment: Heroku uses postgresql as its DB, and it doesnt have strftime function. look at **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119978/equivalent-of-strftime-in-postgres)**. it might help

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.
But it seems impossible to solve immediately.